# Enhancing performance of a gif background rollover

Tags: jquery, html, css, performance, animated-gif

I made a cool rollover in css which display an animate gif when the parent is hovered.

Here's my code : http://codepen.io/clemeeent/pen/oggzMa

Problem is I will have about 40 .day like that, all playing the animate gif behind the circle at any time. I'm not sure that any browser/computer/connection can handle that much. I tried to figure out a solution like :

```
$( ".day" ).mouseenter(function() {
  $( ".play" ).append( "<img src="http://media.giphy.com/media/5Vb7xQB7Z3ScE/giphy.gif">" );
});
```

But i'm definitly not sure it will be better...

If someone as any idea to enhance that code, it would be really appreciated.

PS : The gif is just a sample, the final result will be really great :p

Comment: Might be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: How about creating those lines with HTML or SVG and animate them with CSS?

Comment: Didn't know Code review ! I can try

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 That might actually be more resource hungry than a simple gif that's loaded once.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 : Also, the gif there is just a sample, it will not look like that :)

Comment: @BramVanroy - Not really. These animations created with CSS can be stopped when they are hidden, while GIFs are constantly playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as already mentioned in comments above

do something like this with css

```css
img {
    border-radius:50%;
}
.day {
    margin: 15px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.play {
    height: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -45px 0 0 -45px;
    z-index: -1;
    transition-duration: 100ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-property: all;
    -moz-transition-duration: 100ms;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 100ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-property: all;
    -o-transition-duration: 100ms;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.play img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.badge {
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    background: #ed2c27;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Satisfy', cursive;
}
.day:hover .spinner {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 95px;
    width: 95px;
    left: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: black;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
.day:hover .spinner:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: black;
    -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}
.day:hover .spinner:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    right: 3px;
    bottom: 3px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: black;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="day">
    <!-- 1 -->
    <div class="spinner"></div>
    <img data-src="holder.js/90x90" class="img-circle" style="width: 90px; height: 90px; background-color:#D3D3D3;" /> <span class="badge">1</span>

</div>
```